# How to search for C#

Tags: support, search

The title says it all. 
On StackOverflow, If I do search "**C#**" (with or without quotes), it will show results contains "C", "C++", "C#", or anything that has "C" in it - but 
not exclusively "C#"

Tagging `C#` is different thing. Need to search something like "*How to concatenate in C#?*"

Comment: "Tagging C# is different thing" it is? Why?

Comment: @RJFalconer, because the question may not have C# tag. C# is just an example, what if some stuff that doesn't have tag for it?

Comment: Then the question is poorly tagged. Such questions would not last long before someone fixed the tag. (I.e, "How do I x in [language]?" will be tagged [language] in all cases).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *If I do search "C#" (with or without quotes), it will show results contains "C", "C++", "C#", or anything that has "C" in it - but not exclusively "C#"*

When I typed `C#` into the search box, I found myself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) ([c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)). However, when I searched with the quotes, weird results (doesn't have at least one "c#" word in them) came up.

To search for questions holding the c# tag enclose it in square brackets, i.e, type `[c#] what_ever_you_want_to_search`.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Overflow's core business is being a good Q&A site. The search has always sucked, and always will. Use your favorite web search engine and postfix your query with "site:stackoverflow.com" to search.